# What is the difference between findElement(By) & findElementBy()?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
WebElement p1 = (new FirefoxDriver()).findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'site-title']")) ;

WebElement p2 = (new FirefoxDriver()).findElementByXPath("//div[@class = 'site-title']") ;
```

I m doing same thing: I select element by xpath, but in first line, I do it using `findElement(By.xpath)` and 2nd I use **whole expression findElementByXpath**.

and I still use same firefox driver object!

Is this because **the By.** is interface and accessed differently?

Comment: What language binding you are using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the source code of selenium java bindings, [`findElementByXPath()`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java#448) basically is just a **shortcut** to `findElement(By.xpath, ...)`:

```
public WebElement findElementByXPath(String using) {
    return findElement("xpath", using);
}
```

Comment: you mean according to java doc of selenium?

Comment: @ERJAN please follow the link in the answer (according to the source code, I mean).

Comment: ok, i think i got it, we don't have access to how it is exactly implemented inside, but it is just shortcut

Answer (score -4):

findElement() method -
Identify the one element (text field, label etc) from the web-page

```
WebElement p1 = (new FirefoxDriver()).findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'site-title']")) ;
```

findElements() method -
Identify the multiple elements from webpage, like table rows and colums

```
List<WebElement> p1List = (new FirefoxDriver()).findElements(By.xpath("//div[@table='divTableData']")) ;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: @user,you have it wrong, find Elements returns a LIST of elements, in my case I asked the answer for similar findElement By xpath